# Avoid duplicate code in Controllers and service

Tags: spring, controller

I am using Spring framework.

I wrote some pretty long code to save some results.

So later it turned out in other controllers I will also need this code. Just with small differences for example returning some other strings.

So of course every controller will have its own mapping. So the parameters will be duplicate anyway.
But now for the code inside the mapping method.

I was thinking putting the code in the service of the original controller. Then the other controllers will call this service. The service of course will have plenty of parameters + the slight differences between the controllers. Or should I make like a general service, have good documentation there because of course the methods there will be general and later I should know what they were for.

```
@PostMapping("/testcase") public RedirectView saveResult(Model model, @ModelAttribute("testResultEntity") TestResultEntity testResultEntity, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes , @RequestParam(required = false) String version , @RequestParam(required = false,defaultValue = "0") String page, @RequestParam(required = false) String operation, Authentication authentication,Locale locale) 
{ // here comes long code, which will be used also in other controllers ; 
}
```

Comment: Hello Nina18, can you share some sample code to demonstrate what you're doing? I think it will be easier to understand your problem with some code.

Comment: ok I will do this now

Answer (score 0):

If all the controller mappings have the same signature you can create a parent class with the common implementation.

Something like this:

```java
public abstract class BaseAbstractController {

     // specific logic per controller
     abstract String specific();

    public RedirectView save(Model model, @ModelAttribute("testResultEntity") TestResultEntity testResultEntity, 
         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam(required = false) String version, 
         @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") String page, @RequestParam(required = false) String operation, 
         Authentication authentication, Locale locale) { 
          // here comes long code, which will be used also in other controllers ; 

          String specific = specific();
     }

}

@Controller
public class TestController extends BaseAbstractController {

    @Override
    String specific() {
       return "something"; // here goes your specific logic;
    }

    @PostMapping("/testcase") 
    public RedirectView saveResult(Model model, @ModelAttribute("testResultEntity") TestResultEntity testResultEntity, 
         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam(required = false) String version, 
         @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") String page, @RequestParam(required = false) String operation, 
         Authentication authentication, Locale locale) { 

          return save(model, testResultEntity, redirectAttributes, version, page, operation, authentication, locale);

     }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. But the thing is, in case I will have other duplicate code in the future in some other controller this will also go into this BaseAbstractController and all controllers will again inherit it, even maybe they do not need it.

Comment: You're right, a way to avoid it would be creating specific `Services` and use it whenever it's needed. However, to give a better and more specific software design, it would be good to understand what's being done in the duplicated code. Can you share that? Not the full code but rather an overview of what it does.

Comment: ok . First I check the test result. There is OK , NOK and N/A . If it is NOK then I have to check if user entered text why it was NOK or he chose existing text. If he entered new text I will also have to save that so it will be selectable in the future. In the end I will have to save the test result. That is basically it.

Comment: So yeah you are right. Maybe I should create a SaveTestResultService . This service will only have method saveTestResult. Maybe this is better then having a GeneralService which will be overblown later if it contains to many methods in the future

Comment: For now I will use this solution. I will create a TestResultService . It will have 2 methods. showTestcase and saveTestResult. Because these 2 methods have a lot of duplicate code . And HistoryController, TesterController and AuthorController will have possiblity to show Testcase and update in case